# How do I install adobe flashplayer in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: flash, 16.04, browser, opera

I was wondering how I can install the adobe flashplayer from this site: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

I have no experience with the formats that are available there.

There is no .deb version of it there and I need the flashplayer for Opera.

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You won't be able to install it from that site. I believe Opera has pepper-flash built in which is a more up to date version then the one officially supported from Adobe.

If you still need to install it then add Canonical Partners to your software sources. To do this, go to System Settings, then open Software & Updates and on the tab "Other Software" make sure Canonical Partners is ticked. Then proceed normally with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: I have just tried it and get this error message:

 adobe-flashplugin : Conflicts: flashplugin-installer
                     Conflicts: flashplugin-installer:i386
                     Recommends: adobe-flash-properties-gtk (= 1:20160407.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 adobe-flash-properties-kde (= 1:20160407.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)."

Comment: Then install libappindicator1

Comment: And make sure that the distribution for Canonical Partners is set to your distribution (latest xenial), this is not always the case for upgraded system. Somehow mine was still at raring, probably because it was not checked while upgrading 14.04->16.04

Comment: I get this error `E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @MonaJalal You get `E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate` because you don't select `Canonical Partners` in `Software & Updates`. Read once again @RyanDoherty answer.

Comment: another way  to add "Canonical Partners is to to `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure that  the `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner` line is uncommented (by removing the '#' character at the front)

Comment: Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate