# How do I install Flash on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: firefox, flash

I'm trying to visit a website that requires the use of Adobe Flash, but all it's doing is giving me the following error:

> Please install the Flash player in order to view the broadcast
>   https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer

Is there anything I can do to resolve this error and install Flash on Ubuntu?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, using Firefox as my browser.

Comment: Here is an answer: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/765508/how-do-i-install-adobe-flashplayer-in-ubuntu-16-04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/765508/how-do-i-install-adobe-flashplayer-in-ubuntu-16-04)